# How can I make status bar color match collapsing toolbar color when scrolling?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm making an android app where I have a Material 3 collapsing toolbar that changes color when scrolling down.

I want the status bar color to match the scrim color of the collapsing toolbar. I have tried setting `app:statusBarScrim` but it does not do anything, the status bar stays the same color.

I can't find any solution to this online, but this is an axample of the affect I'm going for:

Normal
[image: Normal]

Scrolled
[image: Scrolled]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while of testing, I solved my issue.

This is a general XML template that should be followed to achieve the Material 3 collapsing toolbar color change effect. When the layout is scrolled, the toolbar changes to the desired color, and the status bar color changes with it.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    ...
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        ...
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            style="?attr/collapsingToolbarLayoutMediumStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/collapsingToolbarLayoutMediumSize"
            app:contentScrim="@color/the_color_you_want"
            app:statusBarScrim="@color/the_color_you_want">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                ...
                android:elevation="0dp" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    ...

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting back, AverageMoss..